# HIve sql on aqua studio

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I would like to return all phone numbers that have two hyphens  ex: 999-999-9999

```
SELECT INSTR(phonenumber, '-', 1, 2), phonenumber 
From phonetable
Where length(phonenumber) = 11 
And INSTR(phonenumber, '-') = 1
```

I want return phone numbers Like 999-999-9999

Answer (score 1):

```
select  *
from    phonetable
where   phonenumber like '___-___-____'
```

or

```
select  *
from    phonetable
where   phonenumber rlike '^\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}$'
```

Comment: I would like to return all thousand different numbers with two hyphens in it. the format only applies to two hyphens one after first area code 3 digits and then another one after the second three digits and the rest four numbers.

Comment: Which is exactly what you have requested when I commented and ask for clarification.

Comment: Thanks - i did not see the second part of the solution.

Comment: The 2nd verifies that all the non-hyphen characters are digits but both ways verify the structure of xxx-xxx-xxxx.

Comment: P.s. I've just fixed something in the 2nd solution